# compare with same table without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a branch table:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
| name  | city      | assets |
+-------+-----------+--------+
| cbi1  | bangalore |   5000 |
| cbi2  | bangalore |   8000 |
| cbi3  | katihar   |  12000 |
| icici | purnia    |  15000 |
| cbi4  | nasik     |  18000 |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to find all branches whose assets is greater than any branch in bangalore.

Comment: What a strange request

Comment: It's the kind of problem someone might set as homework

Answer (score 1):

**with subquery**

```
select name from branch where city !='bangalore' and assets > (select min(assets) from branch where city = 'bangalore') ;
```

subquery `select min(assets) from branch where city = 'bangalore'` will give minimum assets value from all `banagalore` branch. 
then compare it with all remaining branch from table

**without subquery**

```
select distinct(b1.name) from branch b1, branch b2 where b1.city !='bangalore' and b2.city ='bangalore' and b1.assets > b2.assets;
```

without using subquery, you need to do self-join of that table.

Comment: 'without subquery'

Comment: @Strawberry got it

Comment: Distinct is not a function

Comment: @Strawberry then what is distinct? How you use it?

Comment: It's not a function. It takes no arguments, so your parentheses are meaningless (and misleading). Instead, it's an operator within the SELECT clause, and applying to all columns within the SELECT.